# How to use (page-source) func using clj-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure

I have seen the desc of `(page-source)` function, but haven't quite understood it. Can anyone help me by giving an example.

Thank you

Comment: Did you actually try to use it (e.g. in REPL) to see what data it returns?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Yes It returns the whole page html code. But I want to know if we can use it for getting html code for certain class/id. Like (page-source "li#foo")

Comment: look at the documentation [git-hub](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#page-source). You only can get code of entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the internal HTML for an element, you can use the `html` function.

So `(html "li#foo")` should work.